# what is the original Unity panel bar color?

Tags: gnome, panel, colors

I want the panel color to be in the same as in Ubuntu Unity 16.04.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://design.ubuntu.com/brand/colour-palette/) you have the full official palette.

The menu bar's color is "Cool grey"

```
Cool grey
Screen
HEX #333333

Print
C44 M34 Y22 K78
Pantone Cool Grey 11
```